# How to get the Sum of a column update every time you search in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get the total sum of "orderPriceEach" column but every time I am doing a search in the search fields the price doesn't change and remains the same.

The search queries are shown below, the `$totalOrderOutstanding` is the sum for the `orderPriceEach` column

```
<?

$myId = 81;
$listId = "ordersItems";

$db1= new DB;

if ($update)
{
    // firstly we need to update orderOutstanding
    $db1->query("UPDATE myorderitems SET orderOutstanding = 0");
    $db->query("SELECT ordersId, ordersQty, ordersPrId, ordersOrId FROM myorderitems, orders WHERE ordersOrId = orId AND orStatus != 'Cancelled' AND orStatus != 'Invoiced' AND orStatus != 'Awaiting invoice'  AND oiSvType != 'Service' ");
    while($db->next_record()){
        list($ordersId, $ordersQty, $ordersPrId, $ordersOrId) = $db->Record;
        $count = $db1->getval("SELECT COUNT(snPrId) as count FROM mySerials WHERE snPrId = '$ordersPrId' AND snOrId = '$ordersOrId'","count");
        $outstanding = $ordersQty-$count;
        $db1->query("UPDATE myorderitems SET orderOutstanding = $outstanding WHERE ordersId = $ordersId");
    }

}

$totalOrderOutstanding = $db1->getval("SELECT SUM(orderPriceEach) as orderOutstanding FROM myorderitems");


if ($searchOrOrderDateYear) $searchOrOrderDateFrom .= $searchOrOrderDateYear."-";
if ($searchOrOrderDateMonth) $searchOrOrderDateFrom .= $searchOrOrderDateMonth."-";
if ($searchOrOrderDateDay) $searchOrOrderDateFrom .= $searchOrOrderDateDay;
if ($searchOrOrderDateYearTo) $searchOrOrderDateTo .= $searchOrOrderDateYearTo."-";
if ($searchOrOrderDateMonthTo) $searchOrOrderDateTo .= $searchOrOrderDateMonthTo."-";
if ($searchOrOrderDateDayTo) {
    $searchOrOrderDateTo .= $searchOrOrderDateDayTo;
}


// set up query
$query = "SELECT orId, orQuId, orCoId, orCnId, orOrderNumber, orDelAdCompany, orDelAd1, orDelAd2, orDelAd3, orDelAdTown, orDelAdCounty, orDelAdPostcode, orDelAdCountry, orClient, orStatus, orOrderDate, orInitials, orArchived, orCreatedBy, orCreatedWhen, orSalesman, orSalesman2, orCommSplit, orTotal, orTaskDate, orABI, orContact, orFile, coName, coId, coPostcode, ordersQty, oiDispatchDate, oiStatus, orderPriceEach, prName, prId
FROM orders o, companies co, myorderitems oi, products pr WHERE o.orCoId = co.coId AND oi.ordersOrId=o.orId AND pr.prId=oi.ordersPrId "; 

// add search elements
if($searchOrId)     $searchQuery .= " AND (o.orId LIKE '$searchOrId%')";
if($searchOrderNumber)      $searchQuery .= " AND (o.orOrderNumber LIKE '$searchOrderNumber%')";
if($searchCoName)   $searchQuery .= " AND (co.coName LIKE '$searchCoName%' OR co.coName LIKE '% $searchCoName%')";
if($searchOrClient) $searchQuery .= " AND (o.orClient LIKE '$searchOrClient%' OR o.orClient LIKE '% $searchOrClient%')";
if($orStatus)       $searchQuery .= " AND o.orStatus = '$orStatus'";
if($searchOrStatus) $searchQuery .= " AND o.orStatus LIKE '$searchOrStatus%'";
if($searchPrName)   $searchQuery .= " AND (pr.prName LIKE '$searchPrName%' OR pr.prName LIKE '% $searchPrName%') ";
if($searchOrSalesman){
    if ($searchOrSalesman == -1)    $searchQuery .= " AND o.orSalesman = ''";
    else $searchQuery .= " AND o.orSalesman = '$searchOrSalesman'";
}
if ($searchOrOrderDateFrom) $searchQuery .= " AND oi.oiDispatchDate >= '$searchOrOrderDateFrom'";
if ($searchOrOrderDateTo) $searchQuery .= " AND oi.oiDispatchDate <= '$searchOrOrderDateTo'";

// view only own records
$showAllRecords = checkAsset("10", $usId, $usGroups, $totalOrderOutstanding);
if (!$showAllRecords)
{
    // get all postcodes area for salesman
    $db->query("SELECT pcId, pcCode, pcUsIdMikrofill FROM postcodes_lv2 WHERE pcUsIdMikrofill='$usId'");
    $searchQuery .= " AND (co.coPostcode LIKE 'xxx%'";
    while($db->next_record())
    {
        $postcode = $db->Record["pcCode"];
        // contruct regular expression
        $regexp = "^";
        for ($i=0; $i<strlen($postcode); $i++) $regexp .= "[".substr($postcode, $i, 1)."]";
        $regexp .= "[[:digit:]]";
        $trace .= "<br>$regexp";
        $searchQuery .= " OR co.coPostcode REGEXP '$regexp'";
    }
    $searchQuery .= ") ";
    
}


$query .= $searchQuery;
$db->query($query);

// number of rows for actual display
$num_rows = $db->num_rows($query);

// finalise query
if ($array[$listId]) $query .= " ORDER BY ".$array[$listId];

$query .= " LIMIT $offset , $maxRecords"; 
$db->query($query);
?>
```

```
<tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="tdListing">Total outstanding:</td>
            <td id="tdListing">&pound;<?= number_format( $totalOrderOutstandings) ?></td>
                <!-- <td> <a href='ordersList.php?update=1'>&lt; update total </a></td> -->
            <td></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: I didn't read all your code but you could use the `SUM` function in your query

Comment: Queries within loops are a very bad idea. They take a long time and increase the server load. You should optimize your main query.

Comment: I've given that a try @Baracuda078 but all the numbers in the price column reset to 0